# Erro ao declarar uma matriz

Tags: c, array, struct, inicialização

Fiz uma matriz[dia][hora], mas recebo erro ao inicializá-la.

Recebo esse erro e não sei como arrumá-lo

> error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '**attribute**' before '=' token

O código está assim:

```
struct horario{
    char M[8][40] = {{"X 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20"},
                    {"S"},
                    {"T"},
                    {"Q"},
                    {"Q"},
                    {"S"},
                    {"S"},
                    {"D"}   };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível inicializar com valor na declaração da estrutura. Pode fazer isto na definição da variável:

```
int main(void) {
    struct horario {
        char M[8][40];
    };
    struct horario hora = { .M = {
        {"X 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20"},
        {"S"},
        {"T"},
        {"Q"},
        {"Q"},
        {"S"},
        {"S"},
        {"D"}}};
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/KVmPsV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/adhzmmtb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/InitializationInStruct.c).

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!